# How to read/write file has big size in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I'm using rn-fetch-blob library to read/write file base64 in React Native. When I read a file (pdf) have big size (~50Mb), I try using readStream and writeStream method of rn-fetch-blob but I got Error: Out of memory. Anyone give me solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `react-native-fs` and you can find from below link
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-access-file-systems-react-native/